# Is it safe to have a website where users can add HTML using tinyMCE? The final HTML will also be stored in a database

Tags: javascript, mysql, tinymce, xss, sql-injection

As a junior developer, I acknowledge my limited knowledge regarding web security. Recently, I integrated a basic **tinyMCE** editor into my company's website, enabling users to edit their profile page. The tinyMCE editor includes a "code" button in the toolbar along with a corresponding plugin, allowing users to save their content in HTML format to the **MySQL** database. However, I am apprehensive about the potential for XSS attacks, SQL injection, or other forms of attack. Given my limited familiarity with these types of attacks, I am uncertain if users could exploit these vulnerabilities to compromise the website's security.

If your response is affirmative, kindly furnish me with a straightforward, *innocuous code illustration *suitable for presentation to non-technical personnel within the company. Additionally, elucidate the potential vulnerability associated with it.

Comment: Sites that allow this kind of thing use a sanitizer to filter out potentially dangerous HTML. It only allows very simple HTML formatting, no JavaScript. Another options is to use markdown or bbcode instead of raw HTML.

Comment: After researching bbcode, I have found out that this plugin has been removed from tinyMCE 6. While implementing bbcode or markdown in website content may pose challenges for both developers and users, I believe it may be worth the effort if it ultimately improves the site's security. Hence, I am willing to explore this option judiciously. Thank you for your attention.